# Eventos periodicos con Moment.js y Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs, calendar

Saludos

Me encuentro realizando una aplicación en la que debo manejar un calendario con eventos que se repiten, pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de generar los eventos que se repitan los días 31 de cada mes, puesto que hay meses que no tienen 31 días, lo ideal seria que en esos meses el día se seteara al ultimo día del mes.

EJ:

```
var interval = moment("2016-12-31T08:00:00");
console.log(interval.format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format())
```

Obtengo

```
2016-12-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-01-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-03-03T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
2017-05-01T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
2017-07-01T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
2017-08-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-10-01T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
2017-12-01T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
```

Hay meses que no salen, pero note que si hago esto:

```
var interval = moment("2016-12-31T08:00:00");
console.log(interval.format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format());
console.log(interval.date(31).add(1, 'months').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format());
console.log(interval.date(31).add(1, 'months').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format());
console.log(interval.date(31).add(1, 'months').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format());
console.log(interval.date(31).add(1, 'months').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').date(31).format());
```

Es decir alternando entre primero setear el día y después agregar el mes, obtengo el funcionamiento deseado hasta el mes de agosto

```
2016-12-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-01-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-02-28T08:00:00-05:00
2017-03-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-04-30T08:00:00-05:00
2017-05-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-06-30T08:00:00-05:00
2017-07-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-08-31T08:00:00-05:00
2017-10-01T08:00:00-05:00 //MAl
```

Alguna idea de como obtener el funcionamiento deseado, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener el último día del mes puedes usar mejor `endOf('month')`:

```js
var interval = moment("2016-12-31T08:00:00");
console.log(interval.format())
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
console.log(interval.add(1, 'month').endOf('month').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```